# An Event Handler when Close Button is clicked in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I was wondering if there are any event handlers if the user clicked the close button in a windows form. My initial plan was when the user clicked the close button, it will return a boolean to the caller or whoever called that form. for example

```
public void newWindow(){

      NewForm nw = new NewForm();
      nw.ShowDialog();
      if(nw.isClosed){
       do something
   }

}
```

is that possible?

Comment: Subscribe to the FormClose or FormClosing events from the form.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms class does esposes some events. Do go through its MSDN. Youll get some idea on how to get the form closing event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .ShowDialog(), you can obtain a result via the DialogResult property.

```
public void newWindow()
{
    Form1 nw = new Form1();
    DialogResult result = nw.ShowDialog();
    //do something after the dialog closed...
}
```

Then in your click event handlers on Form1:

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

If you do not want to open the new form as a dialog, you can do this:

```
public void newWindow()
{
    Form2 nw = new Form2();
    nw.FormClosed += nw_FormClosed;
    nw.Show();
}

void nw_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    var form = sender as Form2;

    form.FormClosed -= nw_FormClosed; //unhook the event handler

    //you can still retrieve the DialogResult if you want it...
    DialogResult result = form.DialogResult;
    //do something
}
```

Comment: in the method buttonOk_Click() can I instead use form closing event? rather than buttonOk_Click()?

Comment: Thanks It worked! I never knew that ShowDialog() returns a dialogresult

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) Event or since you are using `ShowDialog` you can do something like this. You can also change the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) that is returned in the `FormClosing` Event.

```
DialogResult dr = nw.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: You can change the DialogResult in the FormClosing Method of NewForm and test for it with the code that I showed. When you Click the X to close out of the Form the default DialogResult is Cancel

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

You don't need the `if(nw.isClosed)`, the line `do something` will only get executed when `nw` will be closed

If you need to 'return' a value from that dialog, know this: The dialog is not immediatly released when you close it. So you can do something like this:

```
NewForm nw = new NewForm();
nw.ShowDialog();
var x = nw.Property1
```

Comment: It's just an example of what you may want to do if you want to acces a value from the other form. Otherwise, you could replace that by a doSomething() method call or whatever else suits your needs. It will be executed when the dialog form gets closed